# Is there an analogy between the concept of "sefirot" and that of Hindu "devataas"?

Tags: gentiles, theology, avodah-zarah, mysticism-kabbalah

I am an Italian noahide.

I recently discovered that relevant rabbinic authorities have changed the traditional orientation of the Jewish position  towards the Hindu faith, considered in the past to be idolatrous.

This is the declaration that closed the second Hindu-Jewish Summit held in 2008 in Jerusalem, which was also attended by the leaders of the Central Rabbinate of Israel:

**“It is recognized that One Supreme Being in His formless and manifest aspects has been worshipped by Hindus over millennia. The Hindus relate to only the One Supreme Being when they pray to a particular manifestation. This does not mean that Hindus worship ‘idols’. They worship “devataas”, who are manifestations of the One Supreme Being”.**

In this declaration the "devataas" (Hindu deities: in their Pantheon they amount to even 33 million) are qualified as "manifestations of the One Supreme Being".

I wonder if the rabbis have deepened this new Jewish conception of Hinduism, and in particular if an analogy can be drawn between these "devataas" and the "sefirot" of kabbalistic teaching.

Here are some very useful links to find out more about these Hindu-Jewish summits:

http://www.millenniumpeacesummit.org/Hindu-Jewish_Summit_Information.pdf

https://mfa.gov.il/mfa/pressroom/2007/pages/hindu-jewish%20summit%20held%20in%20new%20delhi%207-feb-2007.aspx

https://www.yogaindailylife.org/news/first-jewish-hindu-leadership-summit

Comment: Rabbi Alan Brill explains this view and might have the answer you’re looking for in his book Rabbi on the Ganges: A Jewish-Hindu Encounter.